# Meaning of “how does it stand with something?”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

How does it stand with being?

The above is a question Martin Heidegger asks in his Introduction to Metaphysics. What does it mean? Does it mean ‘how does/has being start/started?’Or does it mean “how is being?”

Comment: It looks like a poor translation to me. Without context, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: How does it stand with England? Well, my lord!

Comment: These questions are about translations from the German. And the least one needs, is a full sentence or paragraph.

Comment: Heidegger joined the NSDAP ('Nazi Party') on 1 May 1933. Donatella di Cesare asserts in her book _Heidegger and the Jews_ that "metaphysical anti-semitism" and antipathy toward Jews was central to Heidegger's philosophical work. Heidegger, according to di Cesare, considered Jewish people to be agents of modernity disfiguring the spirit of Western civilization; he held the Holocaust to be the logical result of the Jewish acceleration of technology, and thus blamed the Jewish genocide on its victims themselves.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey That is a negative fact about Heidegger’s life, but does not have anything to do with my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heidegger is asking 'What is the status of the concept of 'being'?

"How does it stand with [something]?' is a rather old-fashioned and formal way of asking 'How are things with [something]?' or 'What is the situation with [something]', or (also old-fashioned) 'How goes it with [something]?'.

> In his 1935 summer semester lecture course at the University of
> Freiburg, entitled "Introduction to Metaphysics," Heidegger asks a
> seemingly innocuous question: **"How does it stand with being?," or,
> translated in a colloquial sense: "How's it going with being?"** The
> answer is: not well. Today, humankind is consumed by an instrumental
> relationship with beings; we have closed off other world-views,
> forcing all beings—including humans—to show up or reveal themselves in
> only one way, as objects to be efficiently manipulated and controlled.
> The prognosis, according to Heidegger, is bleak.

[Heidegger's Project (State University of New York Press)](https://www.sunypress.edu/pdf/61864.pdf)

> An Introduction to Metaphysics. MARTIN HEIDEGGER. Trans. by Ralph
> Manheim. New Haven: Yale University Press, 1959. Pp. xi, 214.
>
> The unifying theme of the four very unequal essays composing this book
> is nothing less than the meaning of Being. This theme has a semantic
> aspect: What is the meaning of the term 'Being' (das Sein) over and
> against the term 'being' (das Seiende, 'essent' in Manheim's otherwise
> well thought-out translation). **But it also and primarily represents
> the convergence of all sorts of issues that might be expressed,
> confusedly enough, in the following two ways: for any being, what are
> the conditions and consequences of its having a concept of Being; and
> for Being, what are the conditions and consequences of its being
> conceived by a being? Questions which Heidegger himself throws at us
> as, "How does it stand with Being?"** (p. 39). Profound, monumental,
> and hopeless. The union of the semantic with the hopeless questions is
> a hallmark of H.'s philosophy from the very first page of Son and
> Zeit to his latest publications. However, readers unaccustomed to H.,
> will find that An Introduction to Metaphysics offers the advantage of
> focussing occasionally on the semantic-linguistic aspect of the
> question of Being. The first essay begins with what is affirmed to be
> the fundamental question of traditional metaphysics : why are there
> any beings rather than nothing? In asking this, metaphysics has been
> forgetful of the even more basic question: **how does it stand with
> Being?** This forgetfulness, which is metaphysics, began with Plato and
> is the true reason for the Western spirit's degeneration into
> Russo-American technocracies. In preparing German soul and soil for a
> renewal of the questioning of Being, H. believes himself to be
> preparing Germany's historical mission, first in conjunction with and
> later independent of Hitler's conception of that mission.

[Philosophy and Phenomenological Research (part of 1961 review)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2104616)

> stand verb (STATE)   C1 [ I, L only + adj ] to be in, cause to be in,
> or get into a particular state or situation:

[Stand (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand)